# Foreach loop not printing first form

Tags: php, html, loops

I am updating the code of my search page, for some reason if you search any users for example there are three users with the name "Peter" and if you search for them the first Peter prints only the inputs:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="chatting_with" value="userexample"/><input type="hidden" name="chatting_logusr" value="userexample"/><input id="prponclick" class="openchatmsgdevices" type="submit" value="Enviar un mensaje" />
```

But the rest print correctly with the form:

```
<form target="u-n" method="POST" action="open_new_chat_with_user"><input type="hidden" name="chatting_with" value="userexample"/><input type="hidden" name="chatting_logusr" value="userexample"/><input id="prponclick" class="openchatmsgdevices" type="submit" value="Enviar un mensaje" /></form>
```

Heres the full code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../DD/ddd.php");
$logged_user = $_SESSION['valid_user'];
if(!$logged_user){return false;}
$query = "SELECT searched_for FROM searches WHERE `user` = '$logged_user' ORDER BY id_search DESC LIMIT 1";
$run_query = $all_conn->query($query);
$rows_searches = $all_conn->query($query)->fetch();
$searched_for = $rows_searches['searched_for'];
$no_allowed_spaces = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $searched_for);

$query_info = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE nombre LIKE '%".$searched_for."%' OR `user` LIKE '%".$searched_for."%'";   
echo '<div class="n-ovf" style="overflow:auto;">';
if(strlen($searched_for) >= 1)
{echo '<a href="../search/?q='.$searched_for.'&type=search'.'"><div id="search-ico-con"><div id="s-ico-con"></div><div id="s-l-dvsr-con"><div id="s-l-dvsr"></div></div><div id="s-txt-con"><h3>'.$searched_for.'</h3></div></div><div id="s-dvsor"></div></a>'.
'<a href="../search/?q='.$no_allowed_spaces.'&type=tag'.'"><div id="search-hastag-con"><div id="s-hastag-con"><h1>#</h1></div><div id="shtag-l-dvsr-con"><div id="shtag-l-dvsr"></div></div><div id="shtag-txt-con"><h3>'.$no_allowed_spaces.'</h3></div></div><div id="shtag-dvsor"></div></a>';}

foreach($all_conn->query($query_info) as $got_users){
if(strlen($searched_for) == 0){echo '<div class="search-for-something"><h3>Buscar algo....</h3></div>'; return false;}  

echo '<div class="searched-content-info">

<div style="float:left; width:100%; height:0.1px; position:relative; z-index:9586;" class="container-buttons-search-user">

<form target="u-n" method="POST" action="open_new_chat_with_user"><input type="hidden" name="chatting_with" value="'.$got_users['user'].'"/><input type="hidden" name="chatting_logusr" 
value="'.$logged_user.'"/><input id="prponclick" class="openchatmsgdevices" type="submit" value="Enviar un mensaje" />
</form>

 <a href="../success/profile?search_user='.$got_users['user'].'"><input type="button" value="Visitar árbol"/></a>

 </div>'.

'<div class="searched-photo"><img src="'.$got_users['foto'].'"></div>
<div class="searched-names"><h3>'.$got_users['nombre'].'</h3></div>

</div>

<div class="divisor-search-user"></div>';

}

echo '<div class="all-searched-content-divisor"></div>';
echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.